Proxy error when trying to dockerize MERN application
Currently I am developing a MERN application, and I am on the final stage of the development, as I want to dockerize my application. I am using MongoDB locally, using MongoDBCompass. The users will use it too only locally for each computer. Now I want the users to be able to store data inside it for a long time, even after stopping docker and re docker composing up. But currently I get this error, when I try to fetch data from the database from the frontend:
2024-05-01 10:04:44 arkheia-react-client  | Proxy error: Could not proxy request /simulation_runs from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:4000.
2024-05-01 10:04:44 arkheia-react-client  | See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).

This is particularly interesting, because when I try to access the backend, the web page works fine at the address: http://localhost:4000/
I tried different things, even installing the cors package, but to no avail. Here is my docker-compose.yml file:
version: '3'

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: arkheia-client
    container_name: arkheia-react-client
    command: npm start
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/:/usr/app
      - /usr/app/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - backend
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - app-network

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: arkheia-server
    container_name: arkheia-node-server
    command: npm start
    volumes:
      - ./server/:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    depends_on:
      - database
    env_file: ./server/.env
    networks:
      - app-network

  database:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
    - app-network
    container_name: arkheia-database

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
    data-volume:
    node_modules:
    web-root:
      driver: local

and my server.js:
require('dotenv').config() // Require as here are defined MongoDB credentials

const express  = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const { GridFSBucket } = require('mongodb');

const aboutRoutes = require('./routes/about')
const documentationRoutes = require('./routes/documentation')
const simulationRunsRoutes = require('./routes/simulation_runs')
const stimuliRoutes = require('./routes/stimuli')
const expProtocolRoutes = require('./routes/exp_protocol')
const recordRoutes = require('./routes/records')
const resultRoutes = require('./routes/results')
const parameterSearchRoutes = require('./routes/parameter_searches')

// Define multer storage for middle end
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)); 
    }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

const app = express();

// The express middle end
app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }))


app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.path, req.method)
    next();
})

// Connection to the database
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI)
    .then(() => {
        const conn = mongoose.connection;
        gfs = new GridFSBucket(conn.db, {
            bucketName: 'uploads' // The GridFS bucket name
        });

        // Routes
        app.use('/about', aboutRoutes)

        app.use('/documentation', documentationRoutes)

        app.use('/simulation_runs', simulationRunsRoutes)

        app.use('/stimuli', upload.single('movie', (err, req, res, next) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Multer Error:', err);
                res.status(400).json({ error: 'Error during file upload' });
            } else {
                next();
            }
        }), stimuliRoutes);

        app.use('/exp_protocols', expProtocolRoutes);

        app.use('/records', recordRoutes);

        app.use('/results', upload.single('figure', (err, req, res, next) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Multer Error:', err);
                res.status(400).json({ error: 'Error during file upload' });
            } else {
                next();
            }
        }), resultRoutes); 

        app.use('/parameter_searches', parameterSearchRoutes);

        app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
            console.log("Server running in port 4000");
        })
        console.log("Successfully connected to mongodb");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })


module.exports = app;

The frontend's package.json file looks like this:
{
  "proxy": "http://localhost:4000",
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.11.0",
    "react-json-tree": "^0.18.0",
    "react-markdown": "^9.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.16.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "reactstrap": "^9.2.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}

Now here I read about the proxy field that this can cause problems here, but I dont really see how could it affect the docker images. I really don't want to use nginx or any other libraries just for the sake of dockerizing this app.
I left out the Dockerfiles for the frontend and the backend:
Frontend:
# Dockerfile for React client

# Build react client
FROM node:alpine


# Working directory be app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

###  Installing dependencies

RUN npm install --silent

# copy local files to app folder
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm","start"]

Backend:
#  Dockerfile for Node Express Backend

FROM node:alpine

# Create App Directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install Dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --silent

# Copy app source code
COPY . .

# Exports
EXPOSE 4000

CMD ["npm","start"]

Any ideas, what causes the problem? I didn't see the solution to this problem, that is why I am asking for help here.

Inside the frontend container, the backend isn't on localhost. But if the goal is a production image, why use the dev server (rather than building and statically serving the result) at all? Note also that the whole point of using the proxy with the dev server is to reflect what will happen in production - if the frontend actually can't make relative requests, don't pretend it can.

For example here's a different way to set it up (using Postgres not Mongo, but otherwise very similar) with one final container, where the frontend can make relative requests to the backend (because that's what serves it in production) so proxying via the dev server reflects actual production topology.

The answer was to change the proxy field inside the package.json file inside hte frontend part of the application to:
"proxy": "http://arkheia-node-server:4000"
